# Get all rows using like

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have two tables:

City:

```
CityId | Name
-------+-----------
1      | New York
2      | Sydney
```

Firm:

```
FirmId | Name  | CityId
-------+-------+--------
 1     | Firm1 | 1
 2     | Firm2 | 2
 3     | Firm3 | null
```

`CityId` could be null in `Firm` table.

I need to create a query that returns firms by part of city name.

I'm doing it like this for now:

```
declare @cityName varchar(20)
set @cityName=''

select * 
from Firm f
join City c on f.CityId=c.CityId
where c.Name like '%'+@cityName+'%'
```

The problem is that when `@cityName` is empty string I want to get all firms, including firms where city is null.

How can I get all firms when `@cityName` is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a query like this:

```
select * 
from Firm f
left join City c on f.CityId = c.CityId
where isnull(c.Name, '') like '%'+@cityName+'%';
```

[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/270f95/2)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
declare @cityName varchar(20)
set @cityName=''

select * from Firm f
left join City c on f.CityId=c.CityId
where (c.Name like '%'+@cityName+'%' AND @cityName <> '')
OR (@cityName = '')
```

Comment: No, that;s will return firms with null city always but I need to get it only when  @cityName is empty

Comment: @Gleb, Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Use additional logic for the comparison, including a `left join`:

```
select f.*, c.*
from Firm f left join
     City c
     on f.CityId = c.CityId
where (c.Name like '%' + @cityName + '%') or
      (@cityName is null or @cityName = '');
```

Alternatively, you could use `union all`:

```
select f.*
from Firm f join
     City c
     on f.CityId = c.CityId
where c.Name like '%' + @cityName + '%'
select f.*
from Firm f
where @cityName is null or @cityName = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query :

```
declare @cityName varchar(20)
set @cityName=''

select * from Firm f
left join City c on f.CityId=c.CityId
where isnull(c.Name, '') like '%'+@cityName+'%'
```

Comment: @Gleb - Please notice also, you were using `join` which was a mistake for your desired result, you need to use `left join`